# Time zone difference of server and client in android application

Tags: c#, sql-server, timezone, timespan, timezone-offset

I have created a android client server application which involves storing datetime values into database. The server is mssql server. The server side programming is done in c#. The current time is stored in database as datetime2 value. The server time zone is US Mountain Standard Time. And its offset from GMT is -07 hours. That is server time is GMT-7.00. My current local time is GMT+05.30. I have developed this android app to work in GMT+05.30 timezone. So I need to know how to convert the server time from GMT-07.00 to GMT+05.30.

I have founded off the server time and GMT using the following codes.

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
DateTime server=DateTime.Now;
DateTime universal=zone.ToUniversalTime(DateTime.Now); //GMT TIME
//I have found that My server offset from GMT is -07.00 using the below code
TimeSpan offset = zone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
```

When I enter the following values into my server database, it enters into table in this format.

```
Here my local time is: 2014-02-03 20:25:08.0000000

my server time at that moment is: 2014-03-03 07:55:28.0000000   

the utc time at that moment is: 2014-03-03 14:55:28.0000000
```

So in total there is a time difference of about 12 hours and 30 minutes from my server time and local time. If the server at this location goes down by any reason, then the server will run from another location with different time zone and different offset. So the difference between the server time and the local time changes sometimes. This causes a problem to my app, as my values are getting wrong some times. Is there any way to find out the offset when I require and calculate the time of my server and make it same as the local time??

Comment: 1. Never use `TimeZone`. It's deprecated, use `TimeZoneInfo` instead.  2. [Never use `DateTime.Now` in a web app](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).  3.  If you need the UTC time, just use `DateTime.UtcNow`.  4.  I don't see anywhere in your code here where you are interacting with client-side code, but you seem to want to adjust for the client time zone magically?  5.  What are you actually *asking* here? It is confusing the way you have written it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your data as a [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) if you're using SQL 2008 onwards.

That should make things much easier comparing across different time zones. You can then compare using the [ToLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tolocaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)